# My RCA Voyager Tablet is in a bootloop and I can't get into recovery mode

Tags: recovery-mode, boot-loop, unbricking

Can anyone help me please, My RCA Voyager Tablet is in a bootloop and it keeps showing the logo screen. I was trying to install the trwp for my tablet but I think I accidentally put the worng trwp file into my RCA tablet. I tried to go into recovery mode but nothing happened and I tried flashing it but I couldn't find any firmware file for my model ( my model is rct6873W42) I also tried connecting my computer to my tablet and it's not detecting my RCA Voyager Tablet. I hope someone can please help? P.s I also think it's brick but I am not completely sure.